# Small Office WiFi config for iPhones

Tags: firewall, dhcp, wifi, iphone

I purchased an ASUS RT-AC66u wireless router for use in a small office.  I have the router configured as an access point, DHCP is turned off.  It is using a static IP of 10.10.10.251.  My DHCP server serves to any address in the range: 10.10.10.1 - 10.10.10.250.  The other network settings are: 10.10.0.0/255.255.0.0, gateway: 10.10.1.1, DNS 10.10.1.1, 10.10.1.2.

PROBLEM:  iPhones appear to attach to the Wifi when you touch the name of the SSID.  But the Wifi fan icon never shows up in the top left.  However, if I turn off the cellular service, the Wifi icon shows up.

I have verified that Wifi is not being used unless cellular is turned off.

The iPhones are getting an IP and DNS IPs.  They can be pinged from another computer.

All other devices (Androids, Laptops) work with no problem on the network.

I thought that it might be some port that was blocked in my firewall so I picked an iPhone IP and opened everything up for it but the behavior is still the same.

I have 4 iPhone users who's phones all do this same thing.

Any ideas??

Comment: `1.` It's not clear what you think is the problem. Do you think this is an iPhone problem or a network problem? `2.` The ip address of the ASUS is irrelevant unless you're using it as a router. `3.` What subnet mask are you assigning via DHCP? When you say that Androids and laptops work on the network do you mean that they work while connected wirelessly to the ASUS? `5.` How is the ASUS connected to the wired network? If it's connected via it's WAN port then that's incorrect.

Comment: The problem is that iPhones do not use Wifi even though they appear to detect and connect to the office SSID.

Comment: Subnet mask: 255.255.0.0, Yes, other devices connect to and work with the ASUS AP.  The ASUS AP is connect to the network via Lan port, not wan port.